# tar specific files in several different subdirectories

Tags: linux, tar, wildcards

I have the following folder structure

```
A
|-B
| |-C
|   |-1.log
|   |-2.log
|-10.log
|-D
  |-E
  |-F
    |-php.log
    |-H
      |-php.log
```

I want to collect all the log files and the php file present in the H subdirectory and make into a tar.

I tried `tar -czf temp.tar.gz /A/**/*.log /A/D/F/H/php.log`
but it doesn't seem to search recursively in the `A` directory.

I am using Amazon Linux

Comment: The "**" looks wrong.  Try `tar -czf temp.tar.gz /A/*/*/*.log /A/D/F/H/php.log`

Comment: Is the `/` character before the `A` right? Maybe you should try just `A/`...

Answer (score 4):

Don't rely on wildcard matching / shell globbing but instead use the `find` command to find and list the files you want and send that list to `tar` to be archived:

```
find /A/ -type f -print0 -name \*.log | tar -cvf /path/to/file.tar --null -T -
```

Comment: That works, but when untarring with `tar -xvf test2.tar`, it gives me a `tar: A/B/2016-04-15.log: Cannot open: Not a directory` error.

Answer (score 0):

The following command will tar all .log files recursively across all your directory structure from the "." parent directory, if you want a specific file, just filter with greps:

```
tar -cvf file.tar `find . -type f -name *.log`
```